# Android - XML Accessbility Service won't build

Tags: android, xml, service, compatibility

I have written a very simple accessibility service, the code works fine without an xml file defined for metadata but I want to add the xml file for compatibility purposes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
     android:notificationTimeout="100"
     android:description=""
/>
```

However the error I'm getting is none of the 'android:' resources are defined and also I'm not allowed that description.  Although the description happens regardless of what I type or in what string asset I prove.

Anyone have any ideas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggested solutions.  Turns out that you need to have your target build at 14 for eclipse to accept that xml file.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html#configure) it says android 4.0 has the option to configure the accessibility service with xml. Are you using 4.0+?

Also it mentions certain configuration options like `canRetrieveWindowContent` are only available when using the XML configuration. Are you using such options? If not, I don't think you really need the XML configuration.

Comment: I am but I can't find a way to set the description without using the xml

Comment: Description indeed is something you can only set in the meta-data. But this meta-data (and its 'android:' resources) are only available in android 4.0+ SDK. Also you have to use a string asset as description. I reproduced your problem by using android 2.1 + non string asset string.

Answer (score 0):

It needs the xmlns portion....

Comment: This would be a lot better if you were to include more info.